# AWS SES sending mail with attachement using Amazon iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-ios

Does anyone know how to send a mail with an attachment using Amazon SES with the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

To send an email with SES using the iOS SDK you need to create a [AWSSESSendRawEmailRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSESSendRawEmailRequest.html) and make sure that the rawMessage ([AWSSESRawMessage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSESRawMessage.html#//api/name/data)) data format *complies with Internet email standards regarding email header fields, MIME types, MIME encoding, and base64 encoding.*

This means converting the NSData of your attachment to a base64 string and inserting it in the raw email string with all the headers etc.

Such a string may look something like this:

```
        From: "Bob" <bob@example.com>
        To: "Andrew" <andrew@example.com>
        Date: Wed, 2 Mar 2011 11:39:34 -0800
        Subject: Customer service contact info
        Accept-Language: en-US
        Content-Language: en-US
        Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
            boundary="_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2"
        MIME-Version: 1.0

        --_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

        Hi Andrew.  Here are the customer service names and telephone numbers I promised you. 

        See attached.

        -Bob

        --_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
        Content-Type: text/plain; name="cust-serv.txt"
        Content-Description: cust-serv.txt
        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cust-serv.txt"; size=1180;
            creation-date="Wed, 02 Mar 2011 11:39:39 GMT";
            modification-date="Wed, 02 Mar 2011 11:39:39 GMT"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

        TWFyeSBEYXZpcyAtICgzMjEpIDU1NS03NDY1DQpDYXJsIFRob21hcyAtICgzMjEpIDU1NS01MjM1
        DQpTYW0gRmFycmlzIC0gKDMyMSkgNTU1LTIxMzQ=

        --_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2
```

Note that AWSSESRawMessage has a data (NSData) property so this string will need to be converted to NSData before using it in AWSSESRawMessage

Comment: I have tried using the above logic and I am able to deliver the mail but the attachment is not able to view/download. I actually tried with Image attachment and I found the issue that file is corrupt. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Check that the content-type is correct and that the image is converted to base64 correctly