# Send Attachments with SES Amazon in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am successful in sending emails with SES Amazon Service but I am unable to send  Attachments with the email can anybody tell me how I can do this ? I need this is Swift language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS SES sending mail with attachement using Amazon iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095689/aws-ses-sending-mail-with-attachement-using-amazon-ios-sdk)

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095689/aws-ses-sending-mail-with-attachement-using-amazon-ios-sdk

The above post has correct answer.